# change javascript html, use jquery css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a javascript worked html code.  but i dont need a html, i need a jquery css

which have the same functionality.

i try to change  js html by jquery css but it does not worked

js html

```
$('html, div:contains('+yourstring+')', document.body).each(function(){
      console.log(this);
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace(
            new RegExp(yourstring, 'gi'), '<span class=someclass>'+yourstring+'</span>'
      ));
});
```

to css query

```
$('html, div:contains('+yourstring+')', document.body).each(function(){
      console.log(this);
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace(
            new RegExp(yourstring, 'gi').css('background-color' 'blue')
      ));
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example This question does not make a lot of sense. You may want to check out the Tour too to understand how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, this code, will not work:

```
$('html, div:contains('+yourstring+')', document.body).each(function(){
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(
    new RegExp(yourstring, 'gi').css('background-color' 'blue')
  ));
});
```

Since a `new RegExp` is not a jQuery Object, you cannot call `.css()` up it. You must still have an HTML Element or a jQuery Object to work with.

Another thing to be aware of is that `:contains()` is case sensitive. So if you're testing with `"test"` it will not find `"Test"` in your `<div>` element. So you may have some search issues right away with this selector.

Consider this example:

```js
$(function() {
  function replacer(sObj, n) {
    var c = sObj.text().trim().split(" ");
    var re = new RegExp(n, "i");
    var hits = [];
    $.each(c, function(k, v) {
      if (v.match(re) != null) {
        hits.push(k);
        var newObj = $("<span>", {
          class: "highlight"
        }).html(v);
        c[k] = newObj.prop("outerHTML");
      }
    });
    sObj.html(c.join(" "));
    return hits;
  }

  $("div").each(function(ind, el) {
    replacer($(el), "lorem");
  });
});
```

```css
.para {
  margin: 10px;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #ccf;
  padding: 0.02em;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel dictum nunc, nec pellentesque elit. Integer eget tempor tellus, sit amet volutpat purus. Proin magna est, sollicitudin in suscipit quis, tincidunt at lacus. Morbi sollicitudin sit amet justo
  sit amet pellentesque. Nunc placerat ligula sapien, non laoreet tellus dictum ac. Fusce est leo, bibendum ac justo sit amet, rhoncus placerat enim. Mauris sit amet lectus felis. Aenean eget feugiat leo, rhoncus hendrerit felis. Donec placerat mi quis
  justo varius tempor. Nunc ultricies mi in dolor placerat, non consequat est lobortis. Quisque ac libero in sem cursus pharetra. Fusce pretium rutrum viverra.</div>
<div class="para">Nullam tincidunt ut nisl eu venenatis. Duis non finibus orci, nec imperdiet augue. Sed consectetur orci ut magna sollicitudin sagittis. In mattis tempus molestie. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit nulla. Sed scelerisque metus eros, eu molestie felis auctor
  convallis. In tempor mauris non mi bibendum mollis. Nulla eu sapien non mi aliquam interdum. Donec lorem elit, tincidunt nec lorem at, finibus commodo mauris.</div>
<div class="para">Donec non lectus auctor, imperdiet ante quis, varius erat. Aenean vitae mi magna. Nunc dui tortor, dictum volutpat porta quis, hendrerit nec nunc. Morbi blandit, lectus eget ultrices vestibulum, odio arcu rutrum sem, quis placerat lectus dui sit amet
  augue. Phasellus congue gravida tortor. Sed nec mauris tempus, convallis justo ac, sollicitudin mauris. Pellentesque pretium facilisis augue in dignissim. Pellentesque sollicitudin erat vitae consectetur lacinia. Nunc faucibus lobortis sem vel faucibus.
  Suspendisse a ligula aliquet, tempus neque at, egestas mauris. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eleifend felis lorem. Vivamus sollicitudin, purus nec finibus luctus, dui urna tincidunt est, posuere imperdiet erat magna
  quis turpis. Donec vestibulum nisl eu porttitor laoreet.</div>
<div class="para">Duis vel nibh a libero elementum porttitor sit amet feugiat nisl. Quisque nec maximus turpis. Maecenas in libero sit amet urna consectetur posuere. Maecenas vulputate vitae eros a malesuada. Nullam malesuada nulla et varius aliquam. Nulla hendrerit mi
  ac nisi scelerisque, id molestie nibh ultricies. Vivamus venenatis, diam ac vehicula gravida, magna diam consectetur nibh, ac mollis libero enim a orci. Nam tincidunt est id vulputate ullamcorper. In nec lectus blandit, ullamcorper tortor vel, ornare
  neque. In accumsan tempus orci in finibus. Mauris ac fermentum dui, ac volutpat erat.</div>
<div class="para">Praesent sed purus risus. Quisque porttitor suscipit feugiat. Quisque est massa, porttitor ut feugiat vel, consectetur nec mauris. Fusce iaculis lacus vel felis rhoncus accumsan. Vestibulum interdum lacus magna, id gravida tellus sollicitudin in. Cras
  mauris turpis, elementum a imperdiet ut, faucibus sit amet elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec venenatis eget libero ut aliquet. Praesent a mollis est, ut consequat arcu. Sed nec
  molestie diam. Nunc vestibulum consectetur odio non accumsan. Suspendisse eget tempus lacus. Cras quis dignissim odio, eget tincidunt nulla.</div>
```

This might be overboard from what you want to do. It's a good way to highlight words with a loop.

Hope that helps.